# Applescript remove Missing value and unwanted data

Tags: applescript, javascript, trim

I created a script to return some credit card informations from an internal website

```
                            <a href=\"/web/Support.aa/aa/g55erefesfsfsf/4.g.g.5.24.54\">
                                CC<br>Info
                            </a>

                    ", "

                            Visa (9999)

                    ", "

                            Visa (8888)

                    ", "

                            Visa (7777)

                    ", "

                            Visa (666)

                    ", "

                            Alipay

                    ", missing value, missing value, missing value}
```

I have two issue with my script,

1. I can't get rid of the first link with is not a CC numbers
   tried :
   set myRawData to items 2 thru -1 of myRawData as string
   but don't seems to work.
2. I don't manage to remove all the missing values.
3. Can I remove some entry from the list that contain "none" ?

Here is my full script

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell active tab of window 1 to set myRawData to execute javascript "var outPut=[]; var arr=document.getElementsByClassName('sortable fraudScoringTransactionCCSummary');for (var i in arr) {outPut.push(arr[i].innerHTML)};outPut;"
end tell

## set myRawData to items 2 thru -1 of myRawData as string -- not working
set myNewList to {}

repeat with each from 1 to count of items of myRawData
    set itemOnMyList to item each of myRawData
    if itemOnMyList is in myRawData and itemOnMyList is not in myNewList then set end of myNewList to itemOnMyList
end repeat

## not sur
##set myNewList to items 2 thru -1 of myNewList  -- not working

set countHowManyCC to count myNewList


return countHowManyCC
```

Comment: First of all, the first content set in a code block in your OP, the info returned is not in the form of a `list` as posted because it's missing an opening curly brace and a opening double quote `{"`. Second, you asked "Can I remove some entry from the list that contain "none" ?", well there are no entries in the output you posted that contain "none"! Do you perhaps actually mean "missing value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the *returned output* information posted in your OP while adding the missing opening curly brace and a opening double quote `{"` so as to have it compile as a `list`, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* filters out the *first item of the list* as well as the *items* containing `missing value` in order to return a *count of items* that represent the *data*.

```
set myRawData to {"<a href=\"/web/Support.aa/aa/g55erefesfsfsf/4.g.g.5.24.54\">
                                CC<br>Info
                            </a>

                    ", "

                            Visa (9999)

                    ", "

                            Visa (8888)

                    ", "

                            Visa (7777)

                    ", "

                            Visa (666)

                    ", "

                            Alipay

                    ", missing value, missing value, missing value}


set myRawData to items 2 thru -1 of myRawData

set myNewList to {}
repeat with i from 1 to count myRawData
    if item i of myRawData does not contain missing value then
        copy item i of myRawData to end of myNewList
    end if
end repeat

return count myNewList
```

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* adds a second filter to handle *items* containing "none":

```
set myRawData to items 2 thru -1 of myRawData

set myNewList to {}
repeat with i from 1 to count myRawData
    set thisItem to item i of myRawData
    if thisItem does not contain "none" then
        if thisItem is not missing value then
            copy item i of myRawData to end of myNewList
        end if
    end if
end repeat

return count myNewList
```

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any *error handling* and is meant only to show one of many ways to accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

Comment: That seems to generate a duplicate on the first item each time but then I guess I can remove the fist item

Comment: @Low Risk, In your comment you said, "That seems to generate a duplicate on the first item each time but then I guess I can remove the fist item" and I fail to see what you mean as the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ does no such thing! It remove the first item of the list and any item containing `missing value` and there are absolutely no duplicates! That is of course there are no duplicates in the list other then `missing value`.  In other words, the example list originally contains 9 items, the first item is removed, then the `missing value`  items are removed thus leaving 5 items no dups!

Comment: I'm testing with live data with my internal website, and the first item (after the URL been removed) is added twice to the list, but that's fine because I just have to add "set myFinalList to items 2 thru -1 of myFinalList" and I get rid of it. What I mean for the "None" is some time when I have no transaction with credit card I have "None" instead in text, and I would like to exclude this from my list too.

Comment: @Low Risk, The _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ I posted has absolutely no coding and or mechanism to duplicate an item! How you implemented the code is a different story all together! You need to start posting proper compilable examples of your output and code and what you expect the final output to look like! Do you want to filter out items containing `missing value` as well as "none", or just "none"? If just none then change `missing value` to `"none"`. If both, then add another `if` _statement_ directly after the first one and before the `copy ...` line of _code_.

Comment: @Low Risk, I've updated my answer to include filtering _items_ containing "none".